# How to link images in android application?

Tags: android, html, image, eclipselink, r.java-file

I am creating an android application. I have added four images each to be given four separate links, now when I am trying to link the images as per the below code, i am getting errors. Please guide me.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1); 
img.setOnClickListener(new   View.OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(View v){ 
   Intent intent = new Intent(); 
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE); 
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("ac.com")); 
   startActivity(intent); 
  } 
 })
```

Comment: ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://ac.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

Comment: please write code in question itself.

Comment: Can you post the errors 'I am getting errors' is not clear at all.

Comment: @Sandeep Parteek, i tried adding code in question but was getting eror as "Your code is not formatted properly"

Comment: Try formatting it correctly? And post the logcat.

Comment: ac.com is just a junk link, nothing to do with my question. 'I am getting errors' is that the above code i posted does not work.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to provide the protocol in Uri. Try adding "http://" or "https://"?

Comment: @Andrew T, I added http://link in my code, but still not getting.

Comment: Okay.. then, by *getting errors*, do you mean the app crashes? Or nothing happens at all? If the app crashes, then you should be able to see error on LogCat. Post the exception here if available.

Comment: I want to post my code, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1); 
img.setOnClickListener(new   View.OnClickListener(){ 
public void onClick(View v){ 
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE); 
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")); 
startActivity(intent); 
}
});
```

Is it the semi-colon that is missing? Try above code.

Comment: copy code, put four spaces and paste. make sure each code line have four spaces at the start. You can see in preview how your code looks. For more help, see the suggestions from comment box. take a two minute tour at http://stackoverflow.com/help